# Select from table with multiple values

Tags: sql

My query is

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblalumni_member
WHERE   username IN ( SELECT    *
                      FROM      Split('ramesh,sagar,pravin', ',') )
        AND Is_Approved = 1
```

and username field contains multiple values separated by comma. Like `ramesh,sachin,pravin`.

It should give all rows if any of get matched in selected result.
Can you please help me?

Comment: What RDBMS? What columns does your split function return? And do you really mean that the `username` field itself contains comma separated values? Seems unlikely if it is a table of individual members.

Comment: yes username itself contain comma separated values.means username will contain for example like ramesh,sachin,pravin.

Comment: You should re-design your database then. Storing comma separated values in a column is always a sign of a bad DB design.

Answer (score 5):

In case of SQL Server perhaps something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblalumni_member m
WHERE  Is_Approved = 1 AND
       EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM Split(m.username, ',')
          INTERSECT
            SELECT * FROM Split('ramesh,sagar,pravin', ',')
       )
```